# Not getting a notification message when item is added into cart in magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento, loading, cart

When I add an item to the cart, the page will just keep loading. Upon refreshing the page or going back to the previous page, the item can be found in the cart. I am also able to edit and delete whatever item that is in the cart. I have turned off "After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart" but I am still facing the same problem. Is there a file/extension is can edit/download to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom theme?  if so, try reverting back to the standard template.  If you are now seeing the confirmation message when you add to cart, then you have a theme issue.

If you still do not see the message, its time to start looking at the custom modules you have installed.  Disable them all and then start re-enabling them and testing until you find the one which is causing the issue.  Dont forget to flush your caches between each change.